# Eclipse not showing javadocs on hover, but shows them on "Open attached javadocs in browser"

Tags: java, eclipse, hover, javadoc

I have tried adding both the jar files and the url for JavaFX 11 to the "Javadoc location" (see screenshoot) to each jar-file in the user library I'm using in Eclipse, but still it doesnt show the explanation of how the class works when hovering over a class (see screenshoot) (for example https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SplitMenuButton.html). The explanation for how the class works is shown when choosing "Open attached javadocs in browser" though. The explanations for the classes in the standard library is showing upon hovering.

Im using the latest eclipse, 2020-12.

Ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"Latest"_ is not a proper version and it's also unclear to me what you mean exactly by _"javadoc option field"_ and by _"doesnt show class-info"_. Please show screenshots of the hover with the missing Javadoc and how you have configured the Javadoc. If possible, you should only add the source code; Javadoc is only needed if there is no source code.

Comment: Ok. I have edited the post now. I dont want the source code, i want the class information, for example what is show here: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SplitMenuButton.html

Comment: Thanks howlger, I added the source code and then I also got the information about the class upon hover.

Comment: I guess it's because [`https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/element-list`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/element-list) is returned by the server as Base64 encoded octet stream instead of a text file (in contrast to e.g. [`https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/element-list`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/element-list)). Due to this misconfiguration of the server, it probably looks to Eclipse like there is no Javadoc for any of the packages. For JavaFX 11 sources are available. With attached sources, you will also have Javadoc.